# Difficulties compiling a FORTRAN program

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I would like to use some light scattering codes written in Fortran. I am quite familiar with MATLAB and teaching myself C++ but right now Fortran is causing me a lot of grief.

I just got Photran working with Eclipse and it works compiling (using Gfortran from Cygwin as per Photrans instructions) example Fortran programs I have found online.

The main one I would like to get working is here: http://www.ugr.es/~aquiran/ciencia/codigos/homer.f (note over half of it is just console output and comments it seems, the actual code is quite small).

I actually have written a program in Mathematica which do these calculations already, but I feel it would be a good test case to get my hands dirty in Fortran and move to other codes. If anyone could point me in the right direction to get this compiling that would be great. Thanks.

Edit: So I get it as far as compiling it with just up to (just with warnings)

```
OPEN (1,FILE='q.dat')
```

The second I add

```
DO I=1,5
    WRITE (*,*)
END DO
```

I get 3 errors:

[image: Fortran errors]

Once I remove the DO I can add the writing and eg.

```
    WRITE (*,*) 'This code calculates cross-efficiencies for'
```

And it will compile and make the .exe. I am guessing the DO's are causing me a issue.

Comment: You might have better luck if you post some code here, and also the errors you get when you try to compile.

Comment: If you've already got example Fortran programs compiling and, I presume, executing, what is preventing you compiling and executing your own ?  I don't really see your problem and your question is very vague as to what you want to be told.  Oh, I'm certainly not going to read the code you're pointing us at, I might read a reasonable amount of code in your question.

Comment: Read the error message carefully.  Your compiler has really only found 1 error in the code (`Symbol 'i' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`) the other two errors are straightforward consequences of that.

Comment: Oh I see, I removed IMPLICIT NONE and it fixed that one, I can now get down to the SUBROUTINE CALL but there are a bunch more errors. I think actually either Gfortran is not compiling F77 (I think it is?) codes properly. I may just look for a way to convert it to F90 and have a go then. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveHatcher Do not remove `IMPLICIT NONE`. Instead at the top of the program/procedure/subroutine (top level program part that has `DO I=1,5`) write `INTEGER I` declaration. If you use implicit declarations you are open to all kinds of error with wrong typing that are for some reason not catched by compiler. Are you really sure you want to remember whether by default variable/function with name starting with `A` has `REAL`, `INTEGER` or whatever type for each letter in English alphabet?

Comment: Removing `IMPLICIT NONE` didn't fix any problems, it allows the compiler to not report potentially serious problems to you.  Removing `IMPLICIT NONE` makes things worse not better.  If you don't understand why this is so, go to your basic Fortran tutorial and read that chapter again.

Comment: @SteveHatcher About F77: `man gfortran` supports the following standarts: `f95`, `f2003`, `f2008`, `gnu` and `legacy`. *None* of them are F77 (“The default value for std is gnu, which specifies a superset of the Fortran 95 standard that includes all of the extensions supported by GNU Fortran, although warnings will be given for obsolete extensions not  recommended for use in new code.  The legacy value is equivalent but without the warnings for obsolete extensions, and may be useful for old non-standard programs.”) `f95`, `gnu` (default) and `legacy` are AFAIK compatible with F77.

Comment: gfortran compiles f77 just fine, but the code isnt standard f77 anyway.  `implicit none` isn't f77, nor is the unlabeled `do-enddo` construct..

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help guys. I think that should arm me with enough info to get it going from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed the

```
gfortran -ffixed-line-length-n
```

flag, with n as 132 for the source code I linked. I had some other code that does a similar calculation working and it lined up perfectly in Eclipse's guide lines, but this one was way out.
Thanks for getting me on the right track guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler solution. Your code is fixed format,i.e.,so the maximum length of
code line in the source is 72. You just need to put "extra" code in the new line.
It is shown below(line continuation with `.` at column 6)

```
C        1         2         3         4         5         6         7
C23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
      WRITE (*,*) '(For a single particle size, make it equal to the min 
     .imum value)'
      READ (*,*) kr2 
C Just in case Homer cannot handle it...
      IF((KR+4.0D0*KR**0.33333+2).gt.MSIZE) THEN
      WRITE (*,*) 'Sorry, this value is too high'
      WRITE (*,*) 'Please enter a value smaller than', int(msize-4.0D0*m
     .size**0.33333+2)
```

Comment: If your snippet is supposed to be fixed-form as you claim, why do you have parts of statements to the left of column 7 ?

Comment: Actually I do not have, when I posted it came wrong on web.  The  dot .  should appears below letter R, should be  below one space before letter W.

Comment: sorry, should not appear below letter R

Comment: I see, that would work thanks. Either way I am happy I got it working in the end.